# Virtualization support KVM is not enabled on host,

Tags: docker, 23.04

I am using Ubuntu `v23` and i have installed **docker-desktop**. Now when I start i see this prompt:

[image: Virtualization popup error]

Now I have searched over Internet for some solutions. One of them said to use this command: `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` and if this command returns `0` means your machine does not support virtualization.

What should i do? I have latest lenovo thinkpad

Comment: I don't know about Docker Desktop, but plain Docker doesn't need virtualization to run on Linux, so why not try that?

Comment: Docker Desktop uses KVM  which needs vmx. Activate it in Bios (aka EFI-Setup). https://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/solutions/ht500006-how-to-enable-virtualization-technology-on-lenovo-computers

Answer (score 3):

You have to activate virtualization in your BIOS. For me it worked, if you don't see this option it really means that your machine doesn't support virtualization.

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works for me